# Is this Monero python implementation complete & trustworthy?

Tags: development

I am trying to develop a variant of Monero.
Considering the size and the complexity of the original Monero implementation in C++, I figured it might be easier fork this [Python implementation](https://github.com/emesik/monero-python) of Monero.
How complete is it?
Can I test things on it (like using the Monero testnet)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The linked project is not a "Python implementation of Monero". It's a module with a set of tools for interacting with the Monero daemons / wallets amongst other utilities.

From their [docs](https://monero-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> The aim of this project is to offer a set of tools for interacting
>   with Monero cryptocurrency in Python. It provides higher level classes
>   representing objects from the Monero environment, like wallets,
>   accounts, addresses, transactions.

Therefore you cannot use this as a basis to create a "a variant of Monero".